# Angular, controller & service interaction to display json data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angular-services, angular-http

I'm new in Angular 1.5+ and I'm having some small issues with the basics, such as displaying data from a JSON file on the DOM.

So, I'm able to fetch the data fine, (I think, since it console logs okay)

But, then I'm not too sure how to interact with it on the controller, so that it's used on the html

**Service**

```
export default class Gsheets {
    constructor($http){
        'ngInject';

    this._$http = $http;


    var gData = this;

    this._$http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
    })
    .then(function(response) {
    console.log(response.data);
    gData.headers = response.data;
    }, function() {
        alert("Error");
    });
}
```

}

**Controller**

(What do I have to do here?)

```
class EditorCtrl {
  constructor( Gsheets) {
    'ngInject';


    this._Gsheets = Gsheets;
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
       <ul>
         <li ng-repeat="header in $ctrl.gData.headers"></li>
         {{header}}
       </ul>
```

Thank you in Advance, and any help will be much appreciated.

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You store the response headers in a member of the `Gsheets` instance and the `Gsheets` instance as `_Gsheets` in the EditorCtrl.

So you need to reference it like this:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="header in $ctrl._Gsheets.headers">{{header}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you very much sir, I thought it had something to do with the controller, instead of the html elements. Thank you for the help